# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'at_status_default.value'

Tags: magento2, database, upgrade, indexing

I'm actually kind of desperate.
I tried many times to update my Community Edition from 2.2.1 to 2.2.5, always failing due to what I guess is a database inconsistency.
After the update procedure - done with Composer - I get this error:

```
{"0":"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'at_status_default.value' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT DISTINCT  COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id) FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`\n INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store1` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='1' AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='2'\n INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 WHERE (((IFNULL(`e`.`entity_id`, 0) IN (SELECT `catalog_category_product`.`product_id` FROM `catalog_category_product` WHERE (category_id IN ('3')))) AND(IFNULL(`e`.`entity_id`, `at_status_default`.`value`) IN ('228', '230', '254', '256', '258', '259', '261', '265', '266', '267', '268', '269', '272', '273', '274', '275', '277', '278', '280', '281', '282', '283', '284', '326', '327', '329', '330', '331', '332', '333', '334', '335', '336', '337', '338', '339', '340', '342', '343', '344', '345', '346', '347', '348', '349', '350', '351', '352', '353', '354', '355', '356', '357', '358', '359', '360', '362', '364', '366', '367', '368', '369', '370', '371', '372', '373', '374', '375', '376', '377', '378', '379', '380', '381', '382', '383', '384', '389', '390', '392', '393', '394', '395', '396', '397', '398', '399', '400', '401', '402', '420', '421', '422', '428', '430', '442', '444', '445', '446', '448', '449', '452', '453', '456', '457', '458', '459', '460', '461', '462', '463', '464', '466', '467', '468', '469', '470', '495', '496', '497', '498', '499', '500', '501', '502', '503', '504', '505', '506', '507', '508', '509', '510', '511', '512', '513', '514', '515', '516', '517', '518', '519', '520', '521', '522', '523', '524', '525', '529', '531', '532', '533', '534', '535', '536', '537', '538', '540', '541', '542', '543', '544', '551', '553', '555', '556', '557', '558', '559', '560', '561', '562', '563', '564', '565', '566', '567', '568', '569', '571', '573', '583', '584', '585', '586', '590', '591', '592', '593', '594', '595', '596', '599', '600', '601', '602', '603', '604', '605', '606', '607', '608', '609', '610', '611', '612', '613', '614', '615', '616', '618', '621', '622', '623', '624', '625', '626', '627', '628', '629', '630', '631', '632', '633', '636', '639', '641', '642', '648', '650', '651', '653', '656', '657', '658', '659', '660', '663', '664', '665', '666', '667', '668', '669', '670', '671', '672', '673', '674', '677', '678', '679', '680', '681', '682', '683', '684', '685', '686', '687', '688', '689', '690', '691', '692', '693', '694', '695', '696', '699', '700', '701', '703', '704', '705', '707', '708', '709', '710', '711', '712', '713', '714', '715', '716', '717', '718', '719', '721', '722', '723', '724', '725', '726', '727', '729', '730', '731', '732', '733', '734', '735', '736', '738', '739', '740', '741', '742', '744', '745', '746', '750', '753', '754', '755', '759', '760', '761', '762', '763', '765', '766', '768', '770', '771', '779', '780', '781', '782', '783', '786', '787', '788', '790', '793', '795', '796', '798', '799', '801', '803', '804', '806', '807', '809', '811', '812', '814', '815', '817', '821', '822', '824', '826', '827', '829', '830', '832', '857', '858', '859', '860', '865', '866', '867', '868', '869', '870', '871', '872', '873', '874', '875', '876', '886', '888', '889', '894', '895', '896', '897', '898', '899', '900', '901', '902', '903', '905', '906', '907', '908', '909', '911', '912', '914', '915', '916', '917', '921', '922', '924', '925', '926', '927', '928', '930', '931', '932', '933', '934', '935', '936', '937', '938', '940', '941', '942', '944', '946', '947', '948', '949', '950', '951', '952', '954', '955', '956', '957', '958', '959', '960', '961', '962', '963', '964', '965', '966', '967', '968', '969', '970', '971', '972', '973', '974', '975', '976', '977', '978', '979', '980', '981', '982', '983', '984', '985', '986', '987', '992', '994', '996', '997', '998', '999', '1000', '1001', '1002', '1003', '1004', '1011', '1013', '1014', '1016', '1017', '1018', '1019', '1020', '1022', '1023', '1024', '1025', '1027', '1028', '1029', '1030', '1031', '1032', '1033', '1034', '1035', '1036', '1037', '1038', '1039', '1040', '1041', '1042', '1043', '1044', '1045', '1046', '1047', '1048', '1049', '1050', '1051', '1052', '1053', '1054', '1055', '1056', '1057', '1058', '1059', '1060', '1061', '1065', '1066', '1067', '1068', '1069', '1070', '1071', '1072', '1074', '1075', '1076', '1077', '1078', '1079', '1080', '1081', '1082', '1083', '1084', '1085', '1098', '1099', '1100', '1101', '1102', '1103', '1104', '1105')) AND(IFNULL(`e`.`entity_id`, `at_featured_default`.`value`) IN ('280', '328', '333', '453', '469', '500', '540', '572', '573', '574', '575', '581', '585', '590', '591', '601', '602', '604', '620', '639', '640', '641', '647', '649', '650', '660', '661', '662', '672', '674', '745', '859', '873', '924')) ))","1":"#0 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/DB\/Statement\/Pdo\/Mysql.php(93): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)\n#1 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/vendor\/magento\/zendframework1\/library\/Zend\/Db\/Statement.php(303): Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Statement\\Pdo\\Mysql->_execute(Array)\n#2 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/vendor\/magento\/zendframework1\/library\/Zend\/Db\/Adapter\/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)\n#3 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/vendor\/magento\/zendframework1\/library\/Zend\/Db\/Adapter\/Pdo\/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT DISTINCT...', Array)\n#4 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/DB\/Adapter\/Pdo\/Mysql.php(533): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT DISTINCT...', Array)\n#5 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/DB\/Adapter\/Pdo\/Mysql.php(596): Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Mysql->_query('SELECT DISTINCT...', Array)\n#6 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/vendor\/magento\/zendframework1\/library\/Zend\/Db\/Adapter\/Abstract.php(828): Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Mysql->query(Object(Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Select), Array)\n#7 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Data\/Collection\/AbstractDb.php(220): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne(Object(Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Select), Array)\n#8 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Data\/Collection.php(257): Magento\\Framework\\Data\\Collection\\AbstractDb->getSize()\n#9 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Data\/Collection.php(243): Magento\\Framework\\Data\\Collection->getLastPageNumber()\n#10 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/vendor\/magento\/module-eav\/Model\/Entity\/Collection\/AbstractCollection.php(1104): Magento\\Framework\\Data\\Collection->getCurPage()\n#11 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/vendor\/magento\/module-eav\/Model\/Entity\/Collection\/AbstractCollection.php(913): Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Collection\\AbstractCollection->_loadEntities(false, false)\n#12 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Model\/ResourceModel\/Product\/Collection.php(758): Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Collection\\AbstractCollection->load(false, false)\n#13 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Product\\Collection->load(false, false)\n#14 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Product\\Collection\\Interceptor->___callParent('load', Array)\n#15 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Product\\Collection\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}()\n#16 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Model\/ResourceModel\/Product\/Collection\/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Product\\Collection\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('load', Array, Array)\n#17 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Data\/Collection.php(831): Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Product\\Collection\\Interceptor->load()\n#18 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/vendor\/magento\/module-catalog-widget\/Block\/Product\/ProductsList.php(366): Magento\\Framework\\Data\\Collection->getIterator()\n#19 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/vendor\/magento\/module-page-cache\/Model\/Layout\/LayoutPlugin.php(71): Magento\\CatalogWidget\\Block\\Product\\ProductsList->getIdentities()\n#20 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\\PageCache\\Model\\Layout\\LayoutPlugin->afterGetOutput(Object(Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor), '\\n<script>\\n    t...')\n#21 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}()\n#22 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Layout\/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)\n#23 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Result\/Page.php(257): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor->getOutput()\n#24 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Result\/Layout.php(170): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page->render(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#25 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#26 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)\n#27 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#28 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Result\/Page\/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)\n#29 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php(139): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#30 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#31 \/var\/www\/avtech-magento-test\/shop\/pub\/index.php(37): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http))\n#32 {main}","url":"\/","script_name":"\/index.php"}
```

I reindexed, flushed and cleaned the cache, upgraded the database and everything I could find browsing online.

Comment: Same issue here after upgrading to 2.2.5. Appears to be directly related to conditions set in widgets on the page that is trying to load. Find any solutions since posting?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/135850)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/135850)

Comment: @DribbleCastle Nothing has changed. I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution or at least a workaround.  It appears the problem was related to an attribute that was migrated from Magento 1.x.  The fix for me was to change the attribute scope (in your case at_status_default) from Store View to Global.  After that my page rendered as expected.

Stores > Attriubtes > Product (see scope column).
Edit attribute > Properties > Advanced Attribute Properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is indexing related issue, if you re-index then it will be fix. Run the below command.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```